# Scala or java lib to resolve host name with specific nameserver

Tags: java, scala, dns, nslookup

Given a hostname like "example.com" I want to get its IP-addreses using specific nameserver.

java.net.InetAddress has

```
 private static InetAddress getByName(String host, InetAddress reqAddr)
```

which looks like what I need, but the blooper is that method is private.

https://github.com/gilt/scala-srv-dns has

```
def lookup(serviceName: ServiceName,
         transportProtocol: TransportProtocol,
         dnsSearchPaths: List[String]): Seq[ServiceRecord]
```

But, again, private method.

So, what lib can I use?
And do you have any idea why the libs listed above have these methods private?

Comment: Is it private ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: The variant that accepts a nameservice address is private, yes: see [the source here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/InetAddress.java#InetAddress.getByName%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.net.InetAddress%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dnsjava was the solution for me (http://www.dnsjava.org/)

```
def lookup(host: String, nameServer: String): Array[String] = {
  val l = new Lookup(host)
  l.setResolver(new SimpleResolver(nameServer))
  l.run()
  if (l.getResult() == Lookup.SUCCESSFUL)
    l.getAnswers().map(_.rdataToString())
  else
    Array.empty[String]
}
```

Comment: And if you want to disable request caching, just do l.setCache(null)